# how to convert a wav to WAVE audio, IEEE Float, stereo 44100 Hz

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-conversion

I am trying to convert a generic audio to a specific format accepted by BOSS RC-5 looper (supported format: WAV 44.1 kHz, stereo, 32-bit floating point), I have downloaded one of the accepted files from the machine and these are the info I've been able to extract:

```bash
$ file  002_1.WAV 
002_1.WAV: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, IEEE Float, stereo 44100 Hz
$ ffprobe 002_1.WAV 
Input #0, wav, from '002_1.WAV':
  Duration: 00:00:02.85, bitrate: 2938 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, flt, 2822 kb/s
```

I tried this but it does not work (the machine does not recognize the file as a supported format:

```bash
ffmpeg -i fanfare.wav -ar 44100 -acodec pcm_f32le output.wav
```

It produces a file with similar but not identical features (notice IEEE is missing and also "2 channel" vs "stereo"):

```
$ file output.wav
output.wav: RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, stereo 44100 Hz
$ ffprobe output.wav
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 2822 kb/s
```

Do you have any clue about what am I doing wrong and how to convert to the same format of 002_1.WAV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes down to just the metadata. FFmpeg forces a WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE instead of a standard WAVEFORMATEX header for PCM data above 16 bits per sample, and the `file` utility magic [database](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/riff) and/or your looper doesn't parse the former structure.

Now, this appears to be a bug in that MS does allow 32-bit float to be described with a WAVEFORMATEX header. I'll send a patch for that. Meanwhile, if you don't mind a hex editor, you can change `FE FF` at `0x14` to `03 00` and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked perfectly I also tried this and it works: sox fanfare.wav -e floating-point -b 32 -r 44.1k output.wav